# Finding median in Spark Streaming

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to write the simplest of code samples:

```
from numpy import median
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)

qs = ssc.queueStream([[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9,9]])
output = qs.foreachRDD(median)

output.pprint()

ssc.start(); ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I would like to generate the median for each rdd in the stream. My streams come in every 30 seconds.
To test my code I have made a queueStream

when I look at the type for output I get the following:

```
 type(output)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

Why is this the case? When I try to apply `median` to my stream using `map`, it applies the median function to each member of the list one at a time. I would like to apply the median function to the whole RDD as an aggregate, so the `map` function is out of the question.

How can I compute a median of a stream in Spark Streaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @Justin 's answer:  what is happening:

```
median()
```

*is* being applied to each DStream individually.  However the result is not used .. by anyone..  Why?  foreachRdd() is an *action* not a transformation.

You should look at the DStream transformations: e.g. map(): here is code that is not 100% debugged yet - but it provides a structure:

```
from pyspark.streaming import *
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 30)
dataRdd = [sc.parallelize(d, 1) for d in [[1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8,9,9]]]
qs = ssc.queueStream(dataRdd)

def list_median((med,mylist),newval):
    mylist = [newval] if not mylist else mylist.append(newval)
    mylist = sorted(mylist)
    return (mylist[int(len(mylist)/2)], mylist)

medians = qs.reduce(list_median).map(lambda (med,list): med)
def printRec(rdd):
    import sys
    rdd.foreach(lambda rec: sys.stderr.write(repr(rec)))

medians.foreachRDD(printRec)
ssc.start(); ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: I get the error: File "<stdin>", line 1, in list_median
 TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @Michal  I have updated OP: yes there is a bug in getting the correct tuple types at (med,mylist) calling parameters to the list_median.  I have updated OP to say this has an approach- but the calling convention to the function needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `foreachRDD` does not return anything. It is there merely to perform some action. So, you are getting back a void. You may want to take a look at using some of the window operations.